# load more items in viewpager2 when reached end

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load more items in viewpager2 like in recycler view. What I am trying is that whenever I reached the last item, loading the new data. And the data is loading successfully and set into the viewpager2 but the viewpager2 is like refreshing and go to the first position and again when I reached to the last item it loads the data and set into the viewpager2 but again it goes to the first item.
So, my question is that how can I load more data in viewpager2 like recyclerview

Some Code what I am trying is

it loads the data successfully in getPostsList() method

```
 statusModelList.add(new StatusModel(url, userImg, postId, userName, pRating, uId,
                                    String.valueOf(ratings), ratingId, coins, POSTS_LIST_NAME, ""));
                            if (getActivity() != null) {

                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                    if (shimmerFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                        shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                    if (progressIndicator.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                        progressIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                    if (viewPager2.getAdapter() == null) {
                                        statusAdapter = new StatusAdapter(getContext(), statusModelList, starClick, trendingClick);
                                        viewPager2.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
                                    }
                                    viewPager2.setPageTransformer(new ZoomInTransformation());
                                });
                            }
```

And loading new data like this

```
  viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                    super.onPageSelected(position);
                                    Log.i(APP_TAG, "item " + viewPager2.getAdapter().getItemCount()
                                            + " " + position);
                                    if (position == viewPager2.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                                        if (value.hasData()) {
                                            getPostsLists(value.getData().getRequestForNextResult());
                                            Log.i(APP_TAG, value.toString());
                                        } else {
                                            Log.i(APP_TAG, "data finish");
                                        }
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Perform pagination or  you can just use a SwipeRefreshLayout for the same to load the data . If this doesn't work then save the position of last item and postreceiving your data set it back to the viewPager

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar i tried to set posotion to viewpager2 after data loading but it doesn't change the position